# How to read a RAID 0 array created in Windows (NTFS)

Tags: mount, restore, dd

A customer came in with a corrupt hard drive. We took the hard drive, and cloned the data, via testdisk, onto a raid 0 array. The reason being is that the HDD was 2TB and the largest SSD we had atm was a 1TB.

The the clone was, apparently, formatted as a .dd drive. We tried to use systool disk image viewer, but the .dd file couldn't be read on that. There were also some other claims that manually changing the .dd file format to a .dmg or .img would also work too, but we weren't going to do that. The reasoning is that, in the past, manually changing file formats has (almost 100% of the times) corrupted the whole file. Changes are, it would probably break this file too.

We then took our next option, which was to get a linux boot, and try to read and modify the .dd drive there. We've been having some issues with setting up a NEW raid 0 array for linux to clone our original raid 0 array files (NTFS) to our new array (FAT32). Again, our stock only has 1TB max. Now we've already figured out a way to create a raid 0 array, but here's where the main issue arises.

When we tried to access the original raid 0 array, ubuntu would show (on disks) that the drives are separate. It also has an error with the mounting too. We tried to figure out a way to mount this raid 0 array, but all of our answer either came up with creating a new array (which would most definitely format the drives, and lose the clone) or nothing. So, we really need to know:

**If we set up a NEW raid 0 on the original drive, would that delete all of the original data?** I most likely know what would happen if we were to setup a new raid array. I'm just asking this since Ubuntu is still fairly new for me.

**Is there any way to mount a win10 raid 0 array onto ubunutu without any data loss?**

**And is there, if possible, any other way to *view and modify* .dd files on windows?**

Just to be clear, we know how to setup a raid 0 array, we just don't know whether setting up an array will delete the original data or not (which I think it'll format the drive). We're trying to look for a way to mount a win10 array to ubuntu.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?